# Search Bar in Table View Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, searchbar

im doing a simple project in Xcode 6 and i want to add search bar in tableviewcontroller but something is not working for me. Im doing it by this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/76519/add-table-view-search-swift

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        return self.filteredProgramy.count
    } else {
        return self.programy.count
    }
}
```

here im getting error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". idk why. whole code is here

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        return self.filteredProgramy.count
    } else {
        return self.programy.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    var program : Program

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        program = filteredProgramy[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        program = programy[indexPath.row]
    }


func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    // Filter the array using the filter method
    var scope = String()
    self.filteredProgramy = self.programy.filter({( program: Program) -> Bool in
        let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (program.category == scope)
        let stringMatch = program.name.rangeOfString(searchText)
        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
    })
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text)
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the search bar specifically and has to do with understanding how to use optionals properly. Which line do you get the error? You are likely doing a forced unwrapping of an optional value and getting nil (as described by the error message).

Comment: here. "    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {"

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: Was `self.searchDisplayController` nil?

Comment: okey. now i fixed it. i go through your answer again and i fixed it. thanks a lot man! i didnt see "self.searchDisplayController is nil."

Comment: Great! Glad you got it sorted out. Please be sure to accept or upvote answers that are helpful. It's really appreciated.

Comment: But I don't have a keyboard in search bar and how can I change position of placeholder?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your question. I'd recommend downloading and checking out the completed sample code from: http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/CandySearch-7.zip

Comment: Or if you still have questions after looking at their sample code you could open up a new question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.searchDisplayController` is nil.

I just downloaded the tutorial's sample code (which you should do as well) and I see that the author has a "Search Display Controller" in their nib file. Check your nib file and be sure that the `Candy Search` controller is hooked up properly.

It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

To get to that image right click on the `Search Display Controller` object in the .xib file. Notice in my image that "Referencing Outlets" has a connection between `searchDisplayController` and `CandySearch`. That's what you are missing.

To create the connection ctrl drag from the `CandySearch` controller to the `Search Display Controller" when you let go of the mouse you will see:

[image]

Click `searchDisplayController` and you should be good to go.

Lastly, you should read up on how optionals work in Swift to help you understand issues like this in the future:

https://developer.apple.com/librarY/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_456

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and found the following to work. The 'cell' variable in your code is nil because while you have set the number of rows, the actual cell object has not yet been created (line cell = UITableView(.. below)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell
    var player : Player

    if self.searchDisplayController!.active {
        var searchCell: AnyObject? = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        if searchCell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        } else {
            cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
        }            

        player = self.filteredPlayers[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableCellNamesEnum.PLAYER_DETAIL_CELL.rawValue, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        player = self.selectedPlayers[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(player.firstName) \(player.lastName)"

    return cell
}
```

Comment: why are you mixing the use of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_: forIndexPath:) `? why do you cast the `searchCell` to `AnyObject`?. and casting the return type of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)` to `UITableViewCell` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Mostly because that was the code used in the example tutorial for that particular release of xCode :)