# unexpectedly found nil URL SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, rss

I'm doing a simple RSS reader, but when I click on any news, the app crashes.

Error: `Error:"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

Here's the code where the problem might be:

```
func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView!)  {
    activityIndicator.hidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Error appears in the following line:

```
activityIndicator.hidden = false
```

Here's the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64nnFMKC1R4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Hi again, I answered your question below but as I mentioned before you should really look into how to use optionals. The error you are getting is the same as from your other question where the variable was also nil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070294/search-bar-in-table-view-swift Basically, if you get that error message it means that you are unwrapping a variable that is nil.

Comment: ohmygod. My bad. I thought i had that problem and now lol. Sorry man again my bad.

Comment: No problem man. Good luck with your project and keep at it and welcome to Stack Overflow. Also, don't forget to upvote answers that are helpful! You now have the ability to do that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `activityIndicator` object is nil. You need to either not make it an outlet and instantiate it in your `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
```

Or you should double check your nib connections to `activityIndicator` and be sure it is connected. In your video I can't see the left side of your Xcode panel so I can't tell if it's connected or not.